# LuaLaTeX runs out of memory

Tags: luatex, nodes, memory

I have a very very long LaTeX file. It's 4536017 characters long and 2119 lines. It's basically one giant equation I generated with a Python script. My problem is when I run `lualatex output.tex` from the command console, I get the error

`! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [node memory size=51712161].`

I'm not sure how this can happen, considering that LuaLaTeX is supposed to allocate memory dynamically?

I'm not sure if it's important, but I also get the message
`*geometry* detected driver: pdftex`. Maybe this is causing the problem? And if so, how do I set the driver to lualatex?

Thanks a lot

Comment: geometry is sadly not updated for luatex85 changes so you might need `\usepackage{luatex85}` so it works, as for your big equation can you not split it into smaller chunks?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much, that worked perfectly :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.